# Colour cells in a TableLayoutPanel with variables during runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel currently with multiple rows + columns. It's populated by a for loop that will be different every time it's run dependant on the output of an SQL Query.

```
void tblTableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == 2 || e.Row == 4)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, r);
        }
    }
```

This is the code I've got currently to colour individual rows, but I'd like to be able to colour individual cells depending on 2 variables (J, and K).

```
                TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label, J, K);
```

Similarly here is a sample of how I've added a label to a cell in the TableLayoutPanel using J and K. Is it possible to overload the CellPaint method to allow J and K to be used in it? or if so how could I go about re-colouring cells during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

CellPaint is an event and not a method. I suggest you create a method **GetColor(int row,int column)** that returns a color **Brush** and then in the CellPaint event call your method with e.Row and e.Column.

Comment: How would this work if I had J and K in the main part of my program, the method, and the event. Wouldn't I have to set J and K in the method somewhere?

Comment: I believe J and K is the row and column index where you add your label. So you are colouring your cells based on the row and column indexes. In the GetColour method you would determine which color to return based on J and K (the row and column index). Or am I misunderstanding you?